# Wpf Button IsEnabled not working

Tags: c#, wpf, if-statement

i have a method that enabling and disabling button in here.My if-else block should do when enter a number to lbDivide the ***'öde', '0' and '00'*** buttons should be active but only activing ***öde*** button.How do i solve this ?

[image: my payment page]

> öde = make payment
>
> > Kişi Sayısı = How many person?

```
private void Bol_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lbDivide.Text = "0";
        btnBol.Opacity = 0.5;
        btnBol.IsEnabled = false;
        lbPayment.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

        if (lbDivide.Text == "0")
        {
            btnQr.Opacity = 0.5;
            btnQr.IsEnabled = false;
            zero.Opacity = 0.2;
            zero.IsEnabled = false;
            double_zero.IsEnabled = false;
            double_zero.Opacity = 0.2;
        }
        else
        {
            btnQr.Opacity = 1;
            btnQr.IsEnabled = true;
            zero.Opacity = 1;
            double_zero.Opacity = 1;
            zero.IsEnabled = true;
            double_zero.IsEnabled = true;
        }
```

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in `if (lbDivide.Text == "0")` and looked in the debugger what code (`if` or `else`) is being executed? What is the value of `lbDivide.Text` in the debugger? Aside from that: Because you are setting `lbDivide.Text = "0";` at the beginning, only the code in the `if` block should ever be executed. (Assuming that `lbDivide` is really just a WPF `Label` and except any situations where someone reacts to the change of the label text and sets it to another value.)

Comment: I set a breakpoint to if and else.Like u said only and first **if** working and gettin **0** value from **lbDiDivide** and the else block is never working.If  if-else block isn't working what can i do/use else? By the way when i try to reset label (with C button) 0 and 00 setting to disable in the main page.I'm confused.

Comment: My problem is lbDivide must not be get 0 or 00 value.When i click the 0 or 00 buttons **öde** button is activing BUT it shouldn't be active.This is a online paymet application and the app creating random price.Thas mean it's critical.

Comment: If you don't want `lbDivide` to be `"0"` every time then remove the `lbDivide.Text = "0";` at the beginning of your method. If `lbDivide.Text` still doesn't have another value then there's some other bug somewhere else in your code.

Comment: it doesn't matter 0 or null it's all i need when lbDivide's text bigger then 0 the buttons will be active when lbDivide null they will disable.Thats it.It can not be that hard to do

Comment: You are setting the lbDivide.Text to "0" and then disabling all the buttons, aren't you? It will never hit the else if that is your code.

Comment: you set **lbDivide.Text = "0";** in first line of method **Bol_Click(..)**, so check **if (lbDivide.Text == "0")** always true. In other words, **if** is always executed, and **else** is never executed. I still don't understand What is the problem you need to solve

Comment: my problem is when lbDivide's value bigger then 0, the **öde,0 and 00** buttons should be active if lbDivide's value 0 **öde,0 and 00** buttons should be deactive that's my problem this project developed an old developer that working we are same company.Now I'm take over this project.If i couldn't explain my self or my problem i'm really sorry about that.

Comment: @TPBAFK The real problem is that in your provided code lbDivide's value will **never ever** be bigger than 0 because of the three main reasons everyone here has explained before. (Setting the `lbDivide.Text` to `"0"` every time at the beginning of the method; disabling `btnBol` after the first click; disabling any user input to `lbDivide` because it's hidden by `lbPayment`.) If you correct these three issues you will most definitely solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know where the error is.

```
private void Bol_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    lbDivide.Text = "0";   /// in this line of code you're basically setting lbDivide.text to be 0 every time the button is clicked, so the else condition will never be met.
    btnBol.Opacity = 0.5;
    btnBol.IsEnabled = false;   /// you're basically disabling the button after the first click.
    lbPayment.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

    if (lbDivide.Text == "0")
    {
        btnQr.Opacity = 0.5;
        btnQr.IsEnabled = false;
        zero.Opacity = 0.2;
        zero.IsEnabled = false;
        double_zero.IsEnabled = false;
        double_zero.Opacity = 0.2;
    }
    else
    {
        btnQr.Opacity = 1;
        btnQr.IsEnabled = true;
        zero.Opacity = 1;
        double_zero.Opacity = 1;
        zero.IsEnabled = true;
        double_zero.IsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've set it to null but didn't worked  then i removed it, same didn't worked.It doesn't make sense to me,green button perfectly working but 0 and 00 buttons doesn't work.Why ?

Comment: can you post the XAML codes please I will try to replicate your app

Comment: @TPBAFK In your posted XAML code `lbDivide.Text` is `"0"` at any time and it's not even visible when it's started. (At least if nobody else is setting it in your code.) It simply can't go into the `else` block if no one is setting this text to another value.

Comment: The conditions seem to be working, the problem might be with the Visual UI as labels sit on top of other labels, what I did was to add a messagebox code to condition 1 and 2... like add to the if statement: MessageBox.show("condition 1 met"); and to the else statement add : MessageBox.show("condition 2 met")

Answer (score -1):

change if(lbDivide.Text == "0") by if(lbDivide.Text.Equals("0"))

Comment: nope same problem and i tried **if (lbDivide.Text == "0" && lbDivide.Text.Equals("0"))**  and  **if (lbDivide.Text == "0" || lbDivide.Text.Equals("0"))** too